# Why is Python code returning 'None' when there is no double print requests?

Tags: python, printing, return, nonetype

This is the beginning of my program in `main()`. The first input request is printing 'None' in the space where the user is supposed to type their input. The user is still able to type the input but I can't get rid of the 'None'.

I've tried modifying where the return statement is located at the end of the `while` statement and that doesn't affect anything (right now it's just been taken out but even when it's included it still returns `None`). I'm not asking it to print twice (as far as I'm aware).

```
while True:
    start = input(str(print('Would you like to find out your USA weather forecast? Please enter YES or NO.\n')))
    if start.upper() == 'YES':
        choice()
    elif start.upper() == 'NO':
        print('*'*31)
        print('Thank you for joining us today!')
        print('*'*31)
        exit(0)
    else:
        print('Please enter a valid response.')
        break
```

Comment: Did you mean: `start = input('Would you like to find out your USA weather ...  ')`?

Comment: `print` returns `None`, which you pass to `input`, which prints it as the prompt…

Comment: Also, I see that quotation mark missing at the end of 'Would you like to find out your USA weather forecast? . That was an error due to the formatting in the text box for asking the question that I missed. In the code, the whole statement is encapsulated.

Comment: I need the input to be converted to a string which is why I added the str.

OH I see it now. I don't need the print statement. I'm not sure why I even added that when later code that asks for input doesn't include it. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you have been looking at the wrong tutorials about using `print()` and `input()`.

Comment: The return value of `input` **is** a string (Python 3), so there's no need to call `str` on that value again.

Comment: I am upvorting your question to balance out whoever did downvote. @afab421 -- I don't know Python but try showing more code… perhaps maybe the calling code and a screenshot where you see the word "None" ( don't know if that's a Python keyword or not so I can't help more)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```
start = input('Would you like to find out your USA weather forecast? Please enter YES or NO.\n')
```

**What's happening:**

To see what's happening in your code, read it from the innermost function call (`print`) to the outermost (`input`). The `print` function call usually prints something to the screen, but it doesn't return a value, so its default return is `None`. Then, you call `str` on that return value. `str(None)` is "None". Then you pass that value to `input`, i.e. `input("None")`. This is what's showing up at your prompt.